# Текст в бордере

Tags: html, css

Начал изучать HTML.

Взял макет, по которому буду делать, и столкнулся сразу с первой проблемой.
Создал границы с белым фоном и не могу понять, как вставить туда текст.
Получается, текст или в центре рамки, или так, что невозможно его вставить в рамку.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #0b2838;
}

p {
  margin-left: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.header__logo {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 33%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul a {
  font: left;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#header {
  background: #e23454;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
}

.borderwhite {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 400px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.profilename {
  color: #0e4d66;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <p>БиСтайл</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <a href="">ПОРТФОЛИО</a>
    <a href="">TWITTER</a>
    <a href="">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a href="">VK</a>
    <a href="">GOOGLE+</a>
  </ul>
  <div class="oneplace">
    <h1 class="profilename">Иванов Сергей Васильевич</h1>
    <div id="first" class="borderwhite" align="center">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: Что есть]

[image: Что должно быть]

Comment: Эм, никто в бордер не вставляет текст. Сделайте под него отдельный блок.

Comment: @E_K Извините, а можете показать наглядным образом. Я полтора дня думаю как это все сделать. Не получается совместить. Или Как сделать белую рамку? Я делаю с помощью бордера- это не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Не спешите делать глобальные вещи, лучше почитайте еще теорию и проверяйте как она работает на практике.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #0b2838;
}

p {
  /*   margin-left: 47%; */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.header__logo {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#header {
  background: #e23454;
}

.b-profile {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-profile__name {
  color: #0e4d66;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <p>БиСтайл</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <a href="">ПОРТФОЛИО</a>
    <a href="">TWITTER</a>
    <a href="">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a href="">VK</a>
    <a href="">GOOGLE+</a>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="b-profile">
  <div class="b-profile__inner">
    <h1 class="b-profile__name">Иванов Сергей Васильевич</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался.
Теперь появилась другая проблема. Когда перемещаю заголовок (h1) вниз, вместе с ним и уезжает вниз белый фон.
Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Добавил ' display: flex; ' Cпасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #0b2838;
}

p {
  margin-left: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 34px;
}

.header__logo {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 33%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul a {
  font: left;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <p>БиСтайл</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <a href="">ПОРТФОЛИО</a>
    <a href="">TWITTER</a>
    <a href="">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a href="">VK</a>
    <a href="">GOOGLE+</a>
  </ul>
  <div class="oneplace">

    <div id="first" class="borderwhite" align="center">
      <h1 class="profilename">Иванов Сергей Васильевич</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался. Теперь появилась другая проблема. Когда перемещаю заголовок (h1) вниз, вместе с ним и уезжает вниз белый фон. Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Добавил ' display: flex; '
Cпасибо за помощь .